# Python Electric Vehicle Charger Mapping: TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, plotly

new to python and working on a project. I am currently trying to pull the list of available charger stations in the USA using Python code from this link: https://plotly.com/python/v3/tesla-supercharging-stations/. It looks like some of the plotly code is out of date and I'm having an issue updating it, specifically with the upercharger_locations.keys()[0:10] script below that is causing the error "TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable".

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

data_matrix = [['Location ID', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']]
first_ten_keys = supercharger_locations.keys()[0:10]

for key in first_ten_keys:
    row = [key,
           supercharger_locations[key]['latitude'],
           supercharger_locations[key]['longitude']]
    data_matrix.append(row)

table = ff.create_table(data_matrix)
py.iplot(table, filename='supercharger-locations-sample')
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A quick fix would be to put the keys in a list: `first_ten_keys = list(supercharger_locations.keys())[:10]`

Answer (score 0):

The `.keys()` method returns a `dict_keys` object that can't be subscripted (as with `[0:10]`) directly. But if you wrap it in a type that does allow subscripting (like a `list`, as @samwise suggested in the comments), you can subscript it.

A possible reason it doesn't allow it, is because it may add some overhead to the `dict_keys` that would always be there, which isn't substantially less than the overhead you're adding by converting the type every now and then.

So:

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

data_matrix = [['Location ID', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']]
first_ten_keys = list(supercharger_locations.keys())[0:10]
```